# With apache htaccess, allow access to files in a subdirectory that are restricted in the parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Given the following structure:

```
/a
/a/b
```

In `/a` I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php\d?|phpt)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

and in `/a/b`:

```
Require all granted
```

The purpose being that, in general, certain file types are not allowed to be accessed, but in a particular subfolder, they are allowed.
However, the parent directive seems to take precedence and I get a 403 response for `/a/b/x.php`, i.e.

How can I do to achieve this using .htaccess files (subdirectory `Require` directive precedence)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/a/b/.htaccess` enclose `Require all granted` in same `FilesMatch` directive you used in parent to deny:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php\d?|phpt)$">
   Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

Note that you could also use: `<FilesMatch ".">` to match all kind of files but that might override some unwanted denials set in Apache server config.

Comment: Thanks, that partly fixed it, at least to show me this was not the core of the problem :) As the 403 persisted, I realized for me the big problem was some intermediary ModRewrite rules. Apparently, when a rewrite is done, the last (top-down) `Require` directive applies. So... I have to rethink the whole model :)

Answer (score 0):

In Apache 2.4 I could not make it work using .htaccess in a sub-folder.  It seems that, despite Allowoverride All setting for the DocumentRoot in httpd-vhosts.conf,  the parent folder's .htaccess somehow takes precedence with respect to authentication.

My workaround was to explicitly allow the sub-folders I want in the parent folder's .htaccess file:

```
    AuthName "This website is by invitation only"               
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "T:/folder-with-your-password-file/.htpasswd"

    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/images/public/(.*)$#i
    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/.well-known/(.*)$#i  
    Require valid-user
```

In the latter example I explicitly allow /images/public/ and /.well-known/ subfolders to be accessed by anyone, and for all the rest I require an authenticated user based on .htpasswd.

Here `=~ m#regexp#` means regular expression `regexp` match and `i` means case-insensitive.

P.S.
In my case the parent folder is the document root `/` and the .htaccess file lives there.